# How do I make things move up in line when other items have been hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, filter, visibility, show-hide

I'm trying to get things to move up when I've hidden other objects, but right now there's just an empty space where the hidden item was. Thanks in advance! Also, [here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXPGufluxY7JvuMdDQhT?p=preview) with the page itself.

CSS:

```
#filters {
top: 10;
left: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed !important;
z-index: 999999;
text-align:center;
}

#filters a:visited {
color:#ffffff;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-style:italic;
background:#6fc8de;
padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
margin-left:3px;
margin-right:3px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

#filters a:hover {
color:#6fc8de;
background:#202020;
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('filters').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('not: ',$(".media").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")));
    $(".media").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")).hide();
    $("." + $(this).attr("rel")).show(500);
  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
    <span class="media filtera"><div id="characterbox">
</div></span>
    <span class="media filterb"><div id="characterbox">
 </div></span>
    <div id="topbar">
    <div class="topbartitle">The Characters</div>
    <a class="topbarnavi" href="/">Home</a>
    <a class="topbarnavi" href="/message">Request</a>
    <a class="topbarnavi" href="/verses">Verses</a>
    <br><br>
    <div class="links">
    <div id="filters">
    <a href="#" rel="media" class="filters">All</a>
    <a href="#" rel="filtera" class="filters">Filter A</a>
    <a href="#" rel="filterb" class="filters">Filter B</a>
    </div></div></div>
```

I tried to break down the html to as little information as possible.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? Please create a [mcve] in your question. Also, consider removing one of the tags and adding jQuery.

Comment: It depends on your html. If you want to have a stack of elements that move up on deletion of a top element, then you should probably be stacking `<div>`s then animating the height of the deleted element. And the movements will be transferred to the rest of the stack due to the nature of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the height of the hidden elements to 0 should shrink everything upwards. I usually do that instead of hiding element when possible.

Comment: How would I specify the height of a hidden element?

Comment: `$(this).height(0)` just use the selector the same way as you do for other elements.

Comment: so like this? `$(".media").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")).hide() + $(this).height(0);`

Comment: Sorry, I just looked through your plunker. You are using masonry for layout, which sets item location based on an array of items. If you want change the layout, it's way easier to remove the elements from the masonry. [see this](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#remove)

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me. How do I change the code to work with the filters and make stuff move? Which script do I put it in? EDIT: They seem to filter properly now, but they're all stacked on top of one another.

Comment: Masonry is controlling the layout of your elements, so you'll have to add and remove elements from the masonry to change the layout. (like how you add elements on line 246). The same guy who makes Masonry also makes [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) which is better suited to filtering content like you want.